# How to solve this type of differential equations using power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

$$ y''(x) + f(x)\cdot y  = 0  $$

I'm struggling with this differential equation and i've stuck every time.

Comment: Doesn't $y=f(x)$?

Comment: no. f(x) is a totally different function

Comment: Is that $*$ multiplication or convolution?

Comment: multiplication. I'm new in LaTeX sorry.

Comment: @MuratGüven use \cdot or \times for multiplication

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that
both $y$ and $f(x)$
have an expansion in
power series in $x$.
Ten we just have to
multiply $y\cdot f(x)$
and get the power series for
$y''$
and equate
$yf$ to $-y''$.

Details.

Let
$y(x)
=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_jx^j
$
and
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_kx^k
$.

Then
$y''(x)
=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}j(j-1) a_jx^{j-2}
=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+2)(j+1) a_{j+2}x^{j}
$
and
$y(x)f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
x^n\sum_{j=0}^n a_jb^{n-j}
$.

Equating the sum to zero,
$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}
+\sum_{j=0}^n a_jb^{n-j}
=0
$
for
$n \ge 2$
and,
for $n = 0, 1$,
$0 = a_0b_0
=a_1b_0+a_0b_1
$.

If
$f(0) = b_0 = 0$,
then
$a_0$ is arbitrary.
Then
$0 = a_0b_1
$
so $a_0=0$ if
$b_1 \ne 0$.

If
$f(0) \ne 0$,
then
$a_0 = 0$
and
$a_1 = 0$.

For $n \ge 2$,
$a_{n+2}
=-\dfrac1{(n+2)(n+1)}\sum_{j=0}^n a_jb^{n-j}
$.

Just the usual power series manipulation.

Comment: Your conclusion for the first coefficients is wrong. Just think about $f(x)=1$ for the well-known harmonic oscillator $y''+y=0$.

Comment: @MartyCohen why you've made an assumption for f(0) = 0 ?

Comment: @MuratGüven : This discussion of $f(0)$ is wrong in the answer. The equations for the powers $n=0,1$ are $2a_2+a_0b_0=0$ and $3a_3+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)=0$, which both are contained in the general recursion formula, which is correct.